# Not able to drag and drop dynamic Text Box inside canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth * 0.75;
c.height = window.innerHeight * 0.75;
//reference to 2d context
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

//------------------------------- Text Box -----------------------------------
var btnTxtbox = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
var tTxtbox = document.createTextNode("Text Box");
btnTxtbox.appendChild(tTxtbox);
document.body.insertBefore(btnTxtbox, c);

font = '14px sans-serif';
hasInput = false;

var imagePaper = new Image();
imagePaper.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg";

drawbackground(c, ctx);

function drawbackground(c, ctx){
    ctx.drawImage(imagePaper,0, 0, c.width,c.height);
}

btnTxtbox.onclick = function(e) {
    if (hasInput) return;
    addInput(e.clientX, e.clientY);
}

function addInput(x, y) {
    
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    
    input.type = 'text';
    input.style.position = 'fixed';
    input.style.left = 130 + 'px';
    input.style.top = 20 + 'px';

    input.onkeydown = handleEnter;
    
    document.body.appendChild(input);

    input.focus();
    
    hasInput = true;
}

function handleEnter(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
        drawText(this.value, parseInt(this.style.left, 10), parseInt(this.style.top, 10));
        //document.body.removeChild(this);
        hasInput = false;
    }
}

function drawText(txt, x, y) {
    ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
    ctx.textAlign = 'left';
    ctx.font = font;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeText(txt, x - 4, y - 4);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas" style="border:1px solid red;"></canvas>
```

I am trying to be able to drag and drop a dynamic text box on a canvas, that have a background image in it.
I am able to create a text box, that gets invoked on the click of the button. The text is dynamic in the sense that, the content is editable.
I am stuck with two things:

1) How to drag the Text Box within the canvas, so that it can be placed at a desired location on the image. I referred this fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9xAGa/

but still could not make it work for me.

2) How can I get my cursor out of the text box, when I am done writing? I have written the code to check for the keyboard Enter key - if (keyCode === 13), But still not able to make it work.

3) Is it at all possible to have multiple buttons, and every button corresponds to invoking a different drag gable shape like this text box? (Have not yet tried it, but that's what I am aiming next)

Link for my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hy35gn1u/5/

I am really stuck at this point, would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please put the code from that fiddle here, in your question, as an edit, and not as an external resource.

Comment: your text within the box is already draggable in your fiddle, click and drag..?

Comment: @zero298 I dont know why, but I am not able to see the image uploaded in the background, even though I just copy pasted the code from my external fiddle.

Comment: @Rachel Gallen I think you are referring to  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9xAGa/ , which I just used for reference to implement some part of it in my fiddle. But it is just not working for me.

Comment: Could anyone please guide me through this?